# how to load my csv file into my database only one time (flask-sqlalchemy)?

Tags: python, csv, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask sqlalchemy to load data from csv into my database and show it on my html page.

```
tbperson = Table('tbpersonen',
          Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
          Column('Name', Integer, nullable=True)

with open('Personencsv.csv','r') as csfile:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
   engine.execute(
       insert query,[{"Name" : row[0]})
```

The problem is. everytime I actualise my html page .the file load again . and then i am having the double amount of data .
how to uploded it only one time. 
i' tried `@app.before_first_request`but i didn't worked .
somehow i have to check if the same file is already in my database if True => don't load , how to do this ?

Comment: Dont put the logic into the code that actualise the html page I think

Comment: if the database is SQLite, you can do a one time import without the need for python: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/

Comment: @v25 i am using a postgresql

Answer (score 0):

**Before inserting data, you can drop the table if exists:**

```
engine.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT").execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name')
```

Comment: that could work but. it will be also problematic .because after i load the table on the database i call it in my html and i make also CRUD on it . so i delete the table everytime ,all the modification i made will gone. sorry for my english

Answer (score -1):

i found the solution i will post it here if someone needs it someday.

i have just to check if table exists in database with

```
if not engine.has_table("table_name"):
`table_name = Table('tbl_name',
 Column('id, Integer, primary_key=True),
 Column('name', Strin, nullable=True))
```

`